# Different authorize servers for DNS "A" record and "MX" record

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

Can we use different authorize server to host A and MX record.
Let I want that my internal DNS server should be authorize for "A" records only and when an email is sent and there is need for MX record it should follow standard rule to en-route its MX record query through ROOT-DNS-->TLD DNS-->Authorize-DNS.

Should this need some configuration changes on my internal DNS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to resolve a different A record without touching the MX records internally. If so, then you can configure your internal DNS however you like but I don't believe that there is any way to define a separation of authority for MX and A records as the MX record may require the A record to resolve.
Similarly you cannot define an MX record as a CNAME but require an A record. 
In the absence of MX resource records, SMTP Relay clients will fall back to A and AAAA resource records, per RFC 2821.
In summary - if you control your internal name servers and aren't just proxying, then you can set up your internal zone files however you like, but trying to centrally delegate the A record while still resolving the MX records is not going to be possible as this could allow corruption of MX record resolution.